# First few words of a chapter/section in small-caps?

Tags: small-caps

Is there a package that automatically tells LaTeX to use small-caps for the first few words (say, three) in a chapter/section/subsection?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Not that I'm aware of. You can use the [magaz](http://ctan.org/pkg/magaz) package to make the whole first line small caps, or you could write a command like this:

```
\def\scwords #1 #2 #3 {\textsc{#1} \textsc{#2} \textsc{#3} }
...
\scwords Lorem ipsum delorem fugit however this goes
```

Then if you need more/fewer words just change the number of parameters in `\scwords`. (It doesn't seem worth the hassle to write an iterating version.)

Making this happen automatically is a little more difficult.

Answer (score 7):

As Fowler wrote, a paragraph is a unit of thought not a length, and the starting of a new paragraph must make a statement in this respect. Just emphasizing one way or another the first line or the first three words might not look good or read good. I prefer
the way the tufte-book class handles it with the `newthought` command (and you can choose how many and what words to capitalize).

```
\providecommand\newthought[1]{%
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\textsc{#1} % small caps text out
}
```

Adding a touch of vertical space makes it even look more professional.
The solution by Will is the simplest, if you wish  to just pick up the first few two-three words, automatically.

You can using it as follows:

```
\newthought{Testing the new thought}
```

Comment: I use this for my body of text, but when I try to use `newthought` command within a footnote, I get an error report ("something's wrong, perhaps a missing `\item`").

Answer (score 6):

I've just encountered this problem myself, re-typesetting some 19th century articles that start with a few words in small caps. My solution was to use the `lettrine` package, and treat the small-capped passage just the same way `lettrine` does, but *without* the initial drop cap.

```
\lettrine[lines=1]{}{I wish} to ask your opinion and procure...
```

produces the *semantic* effect I was looking for (and it sounds like you are), though you might think it's overkill if you're not also going to be using drop caps.

**updated:** I earlier removed what I thought was an extra parameter `[lines=1]`, but it turns out to be crucial in this case: without it, the `lettrine` package leaves an indent in the following line.