# Is there a way to configure a command to affect the following paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs, small-caps

I have made the following small command to insert visible section breaks in a manuscript:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}{
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    \centerline{\char"E030}
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
\makeatother
```

But I would also like to make the first three words of the following paragraph automatically rendered in small-caps without having to manually add an explicit command (such as `\testsc{first three words}`) to do so.

I've read the responses to the question [First few words of a chapter/section in small-caps?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4368/first-few-words-of-a-chapter-section-in-small-caps), and the highest rated response suggests configuring a manual command such as:

```
\def\scwords #1 #2 #3 {\textsc{#1} \textsc{#2} \textsc{#3} }
...
\scwords Lorem ipsum delorem fugit however this goes
```

How might I go about adding the function of the latter command into the former so that `\subsectionbreak` causes the first three words of the following paragraph to render in small-caps?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}{\par %%% <- important addition
  \vspace{1\baselineskip}
  \centerline{\char"E030}
  \vspace{1\baselineskip}
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
  \scwords
}
\makeatother
```

where `\scwords` is the proposed one; then write

```
\subsectionbreak
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...
```

However I don't think this is the better way to do it: I'd surely prefer

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}[1]{\par %%% <- important addition
  \vspace{1\baselineskip}
  \centerline{\char"E030}
  \vspace{1\baselineskip}
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
  \textsc{#1 }\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
```

and then

```
\subsectionbreak{Lorem ipsum dolor} sit amet ...
```

Comment: I tend to agree with you. Sometimes too much automation is too much :)