# Bold first letter combined with smallcaps?

Tags: bold

I am trying to automate this:

[image]

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4387/32679) tip which provides the small caps (cool!) but not the bold first letter. The "bold first letter" answers I found were too convoluted for me to use them with what I already found. Can someone help me out?

```
\documentclass{article}
\providecommand\newthought[1]{%
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\textsc{#1} % small caps text out
}
    \begin{document}

\newthought{\textbf{W}hat you see here} a new thought.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The capital letter of a small cap font is the same as capital letter in normal font so the `W` is the same within `sc` or outside it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or this? This allows you to pass a single argument rather than two. Unlike my original code, this makes an approximate adjustment for the loss of kerning when switching fonts (bold -> small-caps), based on [David's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288472/bold-first-letter-combined-with-smallcaps/288473?noredirect=1#comment697935_288473).

```
\documentclass{article}% don't use minimal for examples
\newlength\ltempa
\newlength\ltempb
\newcommand\newthought[1]{%
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\expandafter\formatnewthought#1\relax}
\def\formatnewthought#1#2\relax{%
  \settowidth\ltempa{\textsc{#1#2}}%
  \settowidth\ltempb{\textsc{#1\mbox{}#2}}%
  \addtolength\ltempa{-\ltempb}%
  \textbf{#1}\kern\ltempa\textsc{#2}%
}
\begin{document}

\newthought{What you see here} a new thought.

\end{document}
```

[image: new thought in one]

Here's a comparison of the current definition, with the kerning adjustment, and my original definition, which made no adjustment for kerning:

[image: vacuum variations]

Comment: I'm also not sure you want the `\addvspace` part.

Comment: yes , like that:-)

Comment: I removed the `\addvspace` part per @cfr's recommendation, and it seems to have done nothing (except removing superfluous space, of course.)

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard Er ... what were you expecting it to do?

Comment: @cfr: I'll have to think about that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

The command `newthought` now has 2 arguments and the 1st is the first letter to be typeset in bold.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\providecommand\newthought[2]{%
   \addvspace{1.0\baselineskip plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}%
   \noindent\textbf{#1}\textsc{#2}% small caps text out
  %\noindent\textsc{\textbf{#1}#2}% prettier code
}
    \begin{document}

\newthought{W}{hat you see here} a new thought.

\end{document}
```

**ps.** I'm not sure you need the `\addvspace` part.

[image]

Comment: Maybe worth noting that this loses kerning. (Inevitably.)

Comment: @cfr if you wanted to put the kerning back you could compare the width  of \textsc{Wh} and \textsc{W\mbox{}h}  and add a a kern of the difference (which ignores the difference between a bold and non-bold first letter, but still.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! You mean like this? (Below, not above, obviously.)